# Why rails reverse order of nested field when object was saved by method save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have built a nested resources between question and answer model. This is form i used to create question, i just wrap info relevant:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Question</legend>
    <%= render 'new_question_fields', question_form: question_form %>

  <legend>Answer</legend>
    <%= question_form.simple_fields_for :answers do |answer_form| %>
      <%= render 'answer', f: answer_form %>
    <% end %>
</fieldset>
```

This is my `answer` partial:

```
<div class="answer_fields well fields">
  <%= f.input :correct, label: 'This answer is correct.' %>
  <%= f.input :content, input_html: { rows: 3, class: 'span6' } %>
</div>
```

This is my index page, display questions:

```
<ul class="questions">
  <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <li><%= question.content %></li>
    <ol class="answers">
      <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
        <li><%= answer.content %></li>
     <% end %>  
    </ol>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

On the page to create new question, I built 4 fields for 4 answer of question. This is html code of 4 textarea when they are render in html:

```
<textarea cols="40" id="question_answers_attributes_0_content" name="question[answers_attributes][0][content]" rows="3"></textarea>
<textarea cols="40" id="question_answers_attributes_1_content" name="question[answers_attributes][1][content]" rows="3"></textarea>
<textarea cols="40" id="question_answers_attributes_2_content" name="question[answers_attributes][2][content]" rows="3"></textarea>
<textarea cols="40" id="question_answers_attributes_3_content" name="question[answers_attributes][3][content]" rows="3"></textarea>
```

Say, i have order of fields is 0,1,2,3, but when i save questions, the orders of answer is reverse, example:

If i type 4 answers `A,B,C,D` corresponding the order of textarea on form is `0,1,2,3`, when the question is saved, it display this: `D,C,B,A`,  it means it saved value of textarea `question[answers_attributes][3][content]` first, then `question[answers_attributes][2][content]`...

**Update:** This is my index and create action in Question controller:

```
def index
  @questions = Question.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
end

def create
  @question = Question.new(params[:question])
  @question.question_type_id = params[:question_type_id]
  @question.user_id = current_user.id

  if @question.save
    flash[:success] = "Successfully created question."
    redirect_to questions_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

My `answer` model:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :question_id, :correct
  belongs_to :question
end
```

what is happen when question is save? is this because method `save` of rails or my display form?

Comment: How you create @questions variable? Do you have any `.order()` code in a controller or default ordering set in a model?

Comment: i just used `@question = Question.new(params[:question])` and `@question.save` to create question object.

Comment: Clarification: how you create that @questions variable **in the index view?** Just show us _index_ action from controller and _Question_ model.

Comment: is there any method so i can reverse order of question's answers?

Comment: In your index view, 5th line: `question.answers.order("created_at ASC")...` or `question.answers.order("created_at DESC")...` - one of it should reverse order I suppose.

Comment: thanks, i used `question.answers.order("id ASC").each`, because i see in database, the order of answers like the order of fields on form. Maybe it is my solution now. Post it in answer and i will accept your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `question.answers.order("created_at ASC")...` or;
- `question.answers.order("created_at DESC")...`

One of it should reverse order.

--

But more on that topic - I guess it's about how stack is handled there. You are creating each answer by passing it as an attribute for question during its' creation and that's probably where's the mix. Logs from Rails & database w/ log_level `:debug` should help to see how it goes into the database.

Also `id ASC` probably works for you because your ids increment with time anyway and then it's just the same as `created_at ASC` - but relying on ids may not always be a good approach since sometimes ids may be random.

Comment: well, i think this is because the `each` loop, when i try to run `@question.answers.each` in console, it also return last answer first and the first answer is last. I don't know why `each` do like that.

Comment: the id is just a sequence integer, it is not random.